# How do I find the error in the yaml file?

Tags: yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
 template:
   metadata:
     labels:
       app: nginx
   spec:
     containers:
     - name: nginx
       image: nginx:1.7.9
       ports:
       - containerPort: 80
```

Comment: Why you think there is an error in the file?

Comment: Put it in a [linter](https://jsonformatter.org/yaml-formatter)? It'll tell you `template` isn't indented correctly.